# Embed not working with google analytics api

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

In the laravel project I'm using `google api` that fetches google analytics report when user logins with his google analytics a/c. But when I try to give embed functionality where user can use it in his websites to show fragments like current online users, country-specific users,etc. It isn't working due to some issues.

simple embed code that user is supposed to fetch data anywhere outside my website:

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com/shareEmbed/id">
```

while I'm testing and pasting the above code in different page, it shows login error as in below image

[image]

please help me!

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong.   Login is required.   The user needs to authenticate to Google analytics before they can view their data.

Comment: I understand that, but what if I want to allow certain data to be accessible without google authentication?

Comment: You can't access a user's data without their permission they have to give your application access to their data.